# Vim ignore case by default, vimrc

Tags: vim

I would like to be able to use '/' and 'f' in vim and ignore case by default. I know that this works if I enter the command `:set ic`, but I don't want to have to enter this command each time I open vim. I tried adding `set ic` to and `:set ic` in my ~/.vimrc but this did not work.

Also, I am using cygwin and zsh, if that's relevant.

Any help?

Comment: Should work. I have `set ignorecase` in my `~/.vimrc`, but full or abbreviated should not matter. Is your vimrc readable? Are you running vim with the correct user?

Comment: Hmm. Well I have other things in my ~/.vimrc and they are working, so I assum this mean it's readable and being used with correct user. I tried `set ignorecase` and that also did not work

Comment: I should mention I am using cygwin and zsh

Comment: Try editing your vimrc from within vim by using `:e $MYVIMRC` and then reload it with `:source $MYVIMRC`.  Make sure `set ignorecase` is at the end of the file just in case something earlier in your vimrc changes the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. Turns it's only not working in vimtutor. I guess .vimrc doesn't affect vimtutor?